# How do I control the list of Pages an author can see?

Tags: plugin-development, pages, admin, user-access

Using one of the role managers,I enabled Authors to edit/create Pages).
The edit/create pages screen shows a tree of all the pages in the system.
Is there a way for (beside going into the core) To controll what parts of that Pages tree each user sees?

For example:

```
Created by user A.
Page A
     A.1
     A.2

Created by user B.
Page B
     B.1
     B.2
```

Today, User A sees User's B Pages and vice versa.
I need That:
- User A sees only Page A and it's child pages.
- User B sees only Page B and it's child pages.
- User C sees only Page A and it's child pages.  (although he did not create them).

Comment: Are child pages under A also created by the user A?

Comment: Not necessarily. I might have several groups of Authors, each assigned to each own Tree of pages. But an author from one group should not be able to touch the pages in another group of Authors. 
I can also consider the ONE Author/Tree if this is much simpler.

Comment: have a look at `pre_get_posts` hook